# Setting and retrieving custom HTTP Headers

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We are testing some preview features on Azure Search with the [1.1.1 SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Search/) and need to send and receive custom HTTP headers on our searches.

Based on the [Migration Guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-dotnet-sdk-migration/) we found that there is an underlying **AzureOperationResponse** that can be used to access the headers.

Right now we are doing our searches with:

`SearchResults result = await client.Documents.SearchAsync(searchText, parameters);`

How can we send/receive custom headers with this SDK version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this with the current SDK is to use the [SearchWithHttpMessagesAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.search.idocumentsoperations.searchwithhttpmessagesasync.aspx) method.

By taking the current code, we can change it to:

```
var customHeaders = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>() { { "header1", new List<string>() { "value1" } }, { "header2", new List<string>() { "value2" } } };
var response = await client.Documents.SearchWithHttpMessagesAsync(searchText, parameters, null, customHeaders);
var headerValue1 = response.Response.Headers.GetValues("header1").Aggregate((x, y) => x + y);
var headerValue2 = response.Response.Headers.GetValues("header2").Aggregate((x, y) => x + y);
SearchResults results = response.Body;
```

This way we can send any custom header and receive any custom header.